# Delete SharePoint Calendar Recurrence Event

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, event-receivers, sharepoint-calendar

Item Deleting event is not fired when delete single recurrence event.

Comment: We have same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It will fire on deleting on entire event. You can try Item Update event for this.

Comment: Yes u r ri8. But when i delete event directly from ribbon, that time item Updated event is not fired and If i open event in Edit mode and delete it then Item Updated event is fired...